# Why Realm Object does not conform CVarArgType?

Tags: swift, nspredicate, realm

I'm trying to make query for child objects by parent. So I have following structure:

```
class A : Object {

}

class B : Object {
    dynamic var parent: A?
}
```

Here is query code that doesn't compile:

```
let parent = A()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parent == %@", parent)
let results = realm.objects(B).filter(predicate)
```

Because class A doesn't conform CVarArgType. Since official documentation advise to use `NSPredicate` I'm curious why it was designed this way and I can't use such predicate?

I use Xcode 7.2 and Realm v0.96.2.

Update #1

Following code works fine:

```
let parent = A()
let results = realm.objects(B).filter("parent == %@", parent)
```

So problem is only with `NSPredicate`.

Comment: Both code snippets, you've posted here are supposed to work. Which version of Xcode/Swift do you use?

Comment: @marius I updated my question with this information. Xcode 7.2 and Realm v0.96.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that user-defined types don't easily conform to `CVarArgType`, even when they are `NSObject` descendants.

As a workaround, you can either stick with `RealmCollectionType.filter` or use `NSPredicate(format:_argumentArray:_)`.

Comment: You're right. I created [issue #3039](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3039) to keep track of that. Thanks.